# Monodroid Sliding Menu can't work at android 2.2

Tags: android, xamarin.android, slidingmenu

I used the SlidingMenu library in my application, according to https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SlidingMenu. I build and run application successfully on the android 4.0+, but I failed run application on the android 2.2, but I saw the android sliding menu https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu, it supports from android 2.1.

This is error code:

```
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x00088>
at Com.Slidingmenu.Lib.App.SlidingActivity.SetBehindContentView (int) <0x00237>
at regrecall.HomeActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x00097>
at Com.Slidingmenu.Lib.App.SlidingActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005f>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ffcb4990-4b21-40ac-9622-acbf3c40174b (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>

  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity.setBehindContentView(SlidingActivity.java:83)
    at regrecall.HomeActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at regrecall.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:153)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/common_background.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020081: .xml extension required
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1824)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:319)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:554)
    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:157)
    ... 26 more
```

Forget me that I can't copy whole log, since the logs on the another machine can't connect to network. I analyse this log, it crashed at SldingMenuActivity onCreate method, it failed to create the listview for the behind view on the activity, but it can work on the android 4.0+, it's too strange.

The problem I found: my listview can't infalte on android 2.2, even my layout is so simple below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Home_MenuList"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is probably a lot more to that stack trace, so post the full one here.

Comment: sure, The log is blew:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)

Comment: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity.setBehindContentView(SlidingActivity.java:83)
at regrecall.HomeActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at regrecall.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:32)
22 [MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: Please add that to your question and not as comments, preferably formatted so it is readable.

Comment: I updated the question, and I found the problem is the listview can't inflate at android 2.2, it's so strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `Caused by` section in your Stack Trace it tells you:

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/common_background.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020081: .xml extension required

There is something wrong with that resource, are any of the `ListViewItem`s using this Resource `Drawable`?

Comment: This image used to android:windowBackground, android:colorBackground,
The strange is the code runs successfully on android 4.0+, but it failed runs on android 2.2.